# MySQL arrange existing table columns

Tags: mysql

How can I change the position of a certain existing column in **MySQL** table?

Ex: I want to move the column *username* from its current position to instead be after all the columns or I want it before any certain column in my table.

Answer (score 104):

You can change the order of columns if you like.

If your username column is varchar(255) then:

```
alter table `mytable` 
change column username username varchar(255) after `somecolumn`;
```

If it helps to better read a table definition, then why not?

Comment: if you use old phpmyadmin, you can go to tab "structure" , then edit your column. simply click on (save), then on "edit" and append "... after some_column" phpmyadmin will prepare your sql and keep the settings like "varchar(255)". eg. you get ""alter table `mytable` 
change column username username varchar(255) "" and then you append it so it will be ""alter table `mytable` 
change column username username varchar(255) after somecolumn "".

Comment: `ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY` is preferable even though `ALTER TABLE ... CHANGE` works. The reason is that the latter has additional feature of changing column name, which makes you type more (which is error prone as you may accidentally change column name :-)

Answer (score 47):

Thanks guys for all of your response, I'm already done with it.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_user MODIFY gender char(1) AFTER username;
```

Well it's just like organizing your table right? you don't want your primary key field to be on the last order of your table, at least I know how to coonfigure it if ever I encounter that problem, I'm trying to get used in text based database and not using gui for now.

Thanks again guys :)

Answer (score 20):

Simple use this Query

```
alter table `admin` modify id int(11) first;
```

or

```
alter table `admin` modify id int(11) after `some_column`;
```

Comment: `ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY` only change the column type and ordering, so it's preferable than `ALTER TABLE ... CHANGE` as it added changing column name as well (which makes you type more).

Answer (score 9):

### Your SQL should look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `Customers` MODIFY `UserName` INT (11) AFTER `Orders`
```

Done!
One line changes position and there's nothing else to do.

---

I advise against [@rahim-asgari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118811/rahim-asgari) recommendation of `ALTER TABLE MYTABLE ADD MYFILED INT( 5 ) NOT NULL AFTER POSITION`, since you'll to:

1. Add a new field
2. Copy old field's data into the new field
3. Modify any constraints/Indexes
4. Delete old field

---

### Syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE `TableName` MODIFY `FieldToBeMoved` [SAME FIELD SETTINGS] [ACTION] `TargetPosition`
```

- **`[SAME FIELD SETTINGS]`**

  Refers to the configuration of your field. TINYINT, VARCHAR, TEXT, etc. Remember to include the size. Ej. `varchar (255)`
- **`[ACTION]`**

  You can move a field **`BEFORE`** or **`AFTER`** a specific field.
  Replace for `BEFORE` or `AFTER` accordingly.

---

### EXAMPLE

If your...

- Table name: `Customers`
- Field to move: `UserName`
- `UserName` settings: `int(11)`
- Target Position (Last field of the table): `Orders`

Answer (score 5):

`ALTER TABLE [tbl_name] MODIFY|CHANGE [column definition] [AFTER|BEFORE] [a_column]` both would work. `MODIFY` would be preferable if you only want to change column order but not renaming. Also, you **CANNOT** combine multiple columns reordering in a single ALTER TABLE statement. I.E. to rearrange integer columns col1, col2, col3 order to be in the order of col3, col2, col1, you will have to do

`ALTER TABLE tbl_name MODIFY col3 int FIRST;
ALTER TABLE tbl_name MODIFY col2 int AFTER col3;`

Answer (score -5):

you cant change the order of existing columns.

but u can delete the column u want to change the position and use this command to add it in your desired position.

```
ALTER TABLE `MYTABLE` ADD `MYFILED` INT( 5 ) NOT NULL AFTER `POSITION`
```

or

to add a field at the beginning of table

```
ALTER TABLE `MYTABLE` ADD `MYFIELD` INT( 5 ) NOT NULL FIRST
```

Comment: +1: Column order is completely aesthetic, and changing that order has no benefit

Comment: @OMG Ponies Ever thought that maybe he wants to change the order for "aesthetic" purposes? You can change the order. There are many answers for this. This response is not good.

Comment: based on the other responses, I think it's simply not true that "you cant change the order of existing columns"