# sqlalchemy Move mixin columns to end

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a sqlalchemy model, where all most all tables/objects have a notes field. So to try follow the DRY principle, I moved the field to a mixin class.

```
class NotesMixin(object):
    notes = sa.Column(sa.String(4000) , nullable=False, default='')

class Service(Base, NotesMixin):
    __tablename__ =  "service"
    service_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String(255), nullable=False, index=True, unique=True)


class Datacenter(Base, NotesMixin):
    __tablename__ =  "datacenter"
    datacenter_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String(255), nullable=False, index=True, unique=True)


class Network(Base, NotesMixin, StatusMixin):
    __tablename__ =  "network"
    network_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)

etc...
```

Now the notes column is the first column in the model/db. I know it does not affect the functionality of my app, but it irritates me a bit to see notes before id, etc. Any way to move it to the end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm late to this question but for reference, if you use SA 2.0, just pass sort_order to mapped_column, for example:

```
class NotesMixin:
    note = mapped_column(String(255), sort_order=999)
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/whatsnew_20.html#orm-declarative-applies-column-orders-differently-control-behavior-using-sort-order

Answer (score 31):

Found a cleaner solution:

Use the `sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declared_attr` decorator in sqlalchemy 0.6.5 (`sqlalchemy.util.classproperty` in sqlalchemy <= 0.6.4)

```
class NotesMixin(object):
    @declared_attr
    def notes(cls):
        return sa.Column(sa.String(4000) , nullable=False, default='')
```

According to the docs, this is "for columns that have foreign keys, as well as for the variety of mapper-level constructs that require destination-explicit context". While this is strictly speaking not the case here, it does so by calling the method (and creating the column) when the subclass is constructed, thus avoiding the need to make a copy. Which means the mixin column will come at the end. Probably a better solution than hacking `_creation_order`...

Comment: I definitely preferred the cleaner solution as it's built into sqlalchemy already.  I notice that the order in which you inherit the mixin matters, if you have multiple declarative base mixins.  That's to be expected I presume.

Comment: While this requires less code, but it feels a little roundabout as it using a "hack" way, that is, a non-intented side effect of foreign key constraint to ensure the ordering. I prefer the `_creation_order` solution as that's the intended way to **EXPLICITLY** set the column creation order, regardless being a FK or not.

Answer (score 12):

The easy answer: just create the database tables yourself, instead of having sqlalchemy do it with `metadata.create_all()`.

If you don't find that acceptable, I'm afraid this would require a (small) change in `sqlalchemy.ext.declarative` itself, or you'd have to create your own metaclass and pass it to `declarative_base()` with the `metaclass` keyword argument. That class will then get used instead of the default `DeclarativeMeta`.

Explanation: sqlalchemy uses the creation order of the column properties, which it stores in the "private" attribute `._creation_order` (generated when Column() is called). The declarative extension does mixin columns by creating a copy of the column object from your mixin class, and adding that to the class. The `._creation_order` of this copy is set to the same value as the original property of the mixin class. As the mixin class is of course created first, it's column properties will have a lower creation order than the subclass.

So, to make your request possible, a *new* creation order should be assigned when the copy is made, rather than taking the original. You could try and make your own metaclass based on this explanation, and use that. But you might also try and ask the sqlalchemy developers. Maybe they are willing to accept this as a bug/feature request? At least, it *seems* like a minor (one line) change, that would not have a any effect other than the change you ask for (which arguably is better too).

Comment: Thanks. Using that info, I did: `NotesMixin.notes._creation_order = 9999`

Comment: Even though with less votes, this should be the "correct" way as it **EXPLICITLY** set the column creation order just as OP asked, regardless column being a FK or not.

Comment: Where do you put the NotesMixin.notes._creation_order = 9999? In the Mixin or in the subclass? Or somewhere else?

Comment: @MarlenT.B. bit late but for everyone else, you can just put it under the class declaration and it'll work fine

Comment: @Pav Sidhu - Unless you import your mixin from another module

Answer (score 5):

One can also change the order of columns upon CREATE TABLE compilation (here exemplified for the `postgresql` dialect):

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles


@compiles(CreateTable, 'postgresql')
def _compile_create_table(element, compiler, **kwargs):
    element.columns = element.columns[::-1]   # reverse order of columns
    return compiler.visit_create_table(element)
```

This then works with `metadata.create_all()`.

Comment: I used a variation of this: add an "ordering" key to each column (i.e. `Column(..., info={'ordering': 0})`) and sort `element.columns` using that key (e.g. `element.columns = sorted(element.columns, key=lambda c: c.element.info.get('ordering')`) in the create table compilation.

Answer (score 2):

I know it has been a while, but I found a very simple solution for this:

```py
class PriorityColumn(Column):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._creation_order = 1
```

This is a drop-in replacement for Column, if you are working with Mixins and you want your Derived class' attributes to be first.

```py
class A:
    a = Column(Integer)
    b = Column(String)

class B(A, Base):
    c = PriorityColumn(Integer)
    d = PriorityColumn(Float)

# Your table will look like this:
#   B(c, d, a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could set the column order (to the last position) on the Mixin using:

```
@declared_attr
def notes(cls):
    col = sa.Column(sa.String(4000) , nullable=False, default='')
    # get highest column order of all Column objects of this class.
    last_position = max([value._creation_order
            for key, value in vars(cls).items()
            if isinstance(value, Column)])
    col._creation_order = last_position + 0.5
    return col

class Service(Base, NotesMixin):
    __tablename__ =  "service"
    service_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String(255), nullable=False, index=True, unique=True)
```

To set the column order based on the location of another column (similar to

> `` alter table `some_table` modify `some_colum` `some_type` after
>   `some_other_column; ``

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3822219/488331)

You can use:

```
@declared_attr
def notes(cls):
    col = sa.Column(sa.String(4000) , nullable=False, default='')
    col._creation_order = cls.some_other_column._creation_order + 0.5
    return col
```

NOTE: If you use `+ 1` you end up 2 columns back. I don't really understand why you can even use a decimal.

To set the column order based off of the location of the first column (make this always the 4th column) you could do:

```
@declared_attr
def notes(cls):
    col = sa.Column(sa.String(4000) , nullable=False, default='')
    # get lowest column order of all Column objects of this class.
    start_position = min([value._creation_order
            for key, value in vars(cls).items()
            if isinstance(value, Column)])
    col._creation_order = start_position + 3.5
    return col
```